# Changing the field order after BCS Association?

Tags: visual-studio, bcs, external-content-type

I’ve created and deployed an External Content Type with Associations. All of the CRUD methods I’ve implemented are working correctly. Here’s my problem – in the View Item, Edit Item and New Item forms, I would like the fields to appear in a specific order, with the associated TypeDescriptors mixed in with the “normal” items. I had them ordered correctly before I created the associations. After the associations were implemented through the Visual Studio BDCM Toolbox, the associated items now appear at the end. When I look at the raw XML in the BDCM, I can see that the TypeDescriptors in my methods are in the order I intend, with the association information contained in the definition for each. I’m convinced that those TypeDescriptor nodes are being skipped though, as they aren’t in that order on the web form and the DefaultDisplayName for each is not utilized, while the associated item display names are used instead (again - at the last fields on the form).

Is there something I’m overlooking here – someplace where I can change the order of fields on my forms?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: No response or further activity so closing.

Comment: @AlexAngas Why did this question get closed?! No activity doesn't mean it's too localized! I'm facing the exact same problem myself! Anyone working with BDC who decides to use associations between their entities will wind up with the same issue.